# How to use FS module inside Electron.Atom\WebPack application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, electron

I need write some data in the file, using FS module (fs.writeFile). My stack is webpack + react + redux + electron.

The first problem was: **Cannot resolve module 'fs'**.
I tried to use

```
target: "node",
---
node: {
    global: true,
    fs: "empty",
}
---
resolve: {
    root: path.join(__dirname),
    fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif']
},
```

After several attempts, the problem is resolved ( **node: {fs: "empty"}** ). But then there was a second problem: [screenshot](http://joxi.ru/Q2KVq7Xu98kyLm.jpg).

```
//In method componentDidMount (React)
console.log('fs', fs);
console.log('typeOf', typeof fs.writeFile);

//By clicking on the button
console.log(fs);
console.log(typeof fs.writeFile);
```

You can see, that **fs** is empty object, and method writeFile no exists. I tried to change the webpack's configuration.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require("webpack");
console.log(fs);
```

In this case **fs** is not empty.

How to solve this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Problem is solved.

Need use in electron app (where you add the bundle):

```
var remote = require('electron').remote;
var electronFs = remote.require('fs');
var electronDialog = remote.dialog;
```

Comment: did you add this to your main Electron process (i.e. main.js)? I added these definitions, but don't know what to do with them...

Comment: Be sure to read up on [`electron.remote`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/remote/): "In Electron, GUI-related modules (such as dialog, menu etc.) are only available in the main process, not in the renderer process. In order to use them from the renderer process, the ipc module is necessary to send inter-process messages to the main process. With the remote module, you can invoke methods of the main process object without explicitly sending inter-process messages"

Answer (score 21):

In addition to the accepted answer.

If you are using **Webpack** (like when you are using Angular, React or other frameworks) `require` will be resolved by `webpack`, which will screw it's usage at runtime.

Use `window.require` instead.

Ex:

```
var remote = window.require('electron').remote;
var electronFs = remote.require('fs');
var electronDialog = remote.dialog;
```

**Note:** There is no need to use remote in order to access any of Node API from a renderer process as it's fully exposed.

```
const fs = window.require('fs');
const path = window.require('path');
```

will do.

## Update

Starting from v5 of Electron, the Node API is no longer exposed by default in the renderer process!

The default for the `nodeIntegration` flag changed from true to **false**.

You can enable it when creating the Browser Window:

```js
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true, // <--- flag
            nodeIntegrationInWorker: true // <---  for web workers
        }
    });
});
```

**The security risk of activating nodeIntegration**

`nodeIntegration: true` is a  security risk only when you're executing some untrusted remote code in your application. For example, suppose your application opens up a third party webpage. That would be a security risk because the third party webpage will have access to node runtime and can run some malicious code  on your user's filesystem. In that case it makes sense to set `nodeIntegration: false`. If your app is not displaying any remote content, or is displaying only trusted content, then setting `nodeIntegration: true` is okay.

**And finally, the recommended secure way from the doc:**

https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content