# FS in Typescript- readFile is not a function

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, electron, fs

I'm attempting to use fs in typescript (in Electron for an angular app) and I'm struggling with importing the library correctly. I've been across the web and finally got it setup properly so it doesn't throw compile time errors like this

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />

import * as fs from 'fs';
fs.readFile('../../client/index.html', 'utf8', (error, data) => {
        // ...
})
```

However, when this code actually runs, it throws an error stating

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_fs__.readFile is not a function
```

Running console.log(fs) shows that fs is a completely empty object.

I don't know enough about Angular or angular+npm cross running to figure it out, does anyone have any ideas?

Here's the package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-tour-of-heroes",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.33",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

and tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Edit: note that the answer must be in TypeScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use FS module inside Electron.Atom\WebPack application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994441/how-to-use-fs-module-inside-electron-atom-webpack-application)

Comment: @SLaks that link doesnt reference TypeScript

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Typescript.

Comment: I think this is a relevant issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5767.