# Unable to require 'fs' with Vue CLI 3

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am developing a scheduling software for Windows 10, using Vue CLI 3.

The app needs to use "fs" module, but .. I could not find the way. There is no webpack config file anywhere. How can I solve the problem?

Vue CLI 3 is so different that I cannot use all the ways introduced at stackoverflow.

Please, help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use FS module inside Electron.Atom\WebPack application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994441/how-to-use-fs-module-inside-electron-atom-webpack-application)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried. But the point is not Electron, but Vue CLI "3". Thank you.

Comment: This is no duplicate - strangely, I can confirm that in my own Vue CLI 3 spawned project, using `https` is no problem at all, while using `fs.readFile()` errors, as fs is just an empty object.

Comment: If you're talking about using Node fs within a clientside vue app, that's not possible; the browser won't give you access to the user's filesystem for obvious reasons.  Might be possible if you're using vue only for serverside rendering and want to read files from the server; I'm not sure about that as I've never tried such a thing.

Comment: I think I had similar issue in the past and it was resolved with https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-system. Can't remember clearly so I might be wrong. But since OP provided very little relevant information, I guess it could be something much simpler.

Answer (score 25):

#### using FS module while bootstrapping the app

You **can** use `fs` when bootstrapping the application. For instance you could read a file in your file system to grab something, then add it to the application to use it somehow. If this is what you want (I doubt), you can just setup something like the following in your `vue.config.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const someFileContents = fs.readFileSync('my-path-to-the-file');

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: true,

  configureWebpack: config => {
    return {
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'somevar': someFileContents,
        })
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

And now, whenever you write `somevar` in your web app code, webpack will had it replaced -at compile time- with the contents of the file. This may have some uses I think, but never did it.

#### Using FS module in browser

Due to security reasons, you **cannot** use the `fs` module in the browser: you won't be able to setup a Vue component that lists filesystem items or write to disk. It is not a webpack, node nor Vue issue, it is due to security limitations of browsers. The native `fs` module of node.js talks to OS low level API's, and the browser can't access them.

should javascript be able to modify or read filesystems, a lot of devastating pretty bad security screw ups will arise.

#### The FileSystem API

Now, there is this pretty new browser API, the [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem).

It does not allow to access user filesystem, yet it somehow simulates a sandboxed folder where your web application can store files. It may be useful for you depending on your use case, but does not have the greatest browser support.

#### Webpack configuration

> There is no webpack config file anywhere.

In fact, all your webpack stuff in a vue-cli 3 app should be done via the `vue.config.js` file: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html.

There you can execute arbitrary node.js code (in fact you can call `fs` from there, as said before, since it is code running on your machine, not in the browser).

Comment: Thanks, the filesystem API was all I needed in the end - since the user chooses to upload the file by dragging it into the window, I didn't need to write or read from the disk after all. Cheers

Comment: I'm getting `webpack is not defined` with the first solution.

Comment: @RedGuy11 I wrote that answer quite some time ago. My best bet is that I missed a `const webpack = require('webpack')` at the beginning but I'm not really sure if that's the case.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Another thing to note that I couldn't figure out (for other people who have the same problem): Webpack will automatically call `JSON.parse` on `someFileContents`, so you may need to call `JSON.stringify` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the webpack conf:

```
node: {
  fs: "empty"
}
```

As @Sergeon stated, `fs` is not for browser usage.

Comment: How to add this through vue.config.js?

Comment: You should have a webpack.conf.js somewhere

Comment: @"Gonzalo Lorieto" Song of the past, maybe... https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#using-resolved-config-as-a-file It is generated dynamically so any changes to it won't persist and should be made via vue.config's configureWebpack and chainWebpack props... and it's hard to deduce the exact content thereof.