# How to fix ' file.writeFile is not a function ' in vuejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vue.js to display json data from a locally stored file in a table on the web page. I also want to update the data in the json file by using data from a form. But I get the error mentioned above

```
import json from "../assets/data.json";
    export default{
        json,
        data(){
            return{
                title: '',
                date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
                modal: false,
                menu2: false,
                dialog: false,
                notifications: false,
                sound: true,
                widgets: false,
                task: '',
                tasks: {},
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submit: function(){
                this.tasks = {id: json.length+1, task:this.task,date: this.date, complete: false}
                json.push(this.tasks)
                var file = require('fs')
                file.writeFile('../assets/data.json', json)
            }
            reset1(){
                this.task = '';
                this.date = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
            }
        },
        name: "Form"
    };
</script>
```

Comment: this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420663/unable-to-require-fs-with-vue-cli-3

Comment: This is probably not a "locally stored file" since your web page will be executing on the client side.