# npm dree folder structure to JSON

Tags: vue.js, npm, directory-structure

i am trying to use dree to get the folder structure as a json object.

i have installed the package following the link :  https://www.npmjs.com/package/dree

To test i have given the path to my components folder in my project

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App "/>
  </div>
</template>



 <script>
    import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

    const dree = require('dree');
    const tree = dree.scan('./components'); 
    console.log(tree);

    export default {
      name: 'app',
      components: {
        HelloWorld
      }
    }
    </script>
```

If I console.log (dree) then it's giving me the result  but console.log(tree);
is giving me the below error. Please help.

index.js?517d:325 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'sizeInBytes' of null`enter code here` at Object.scan (index.js?517d:325)

Comment: This library seems to be `node.js` only as it goes through the directory path. You cannot use it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Dree uses the node fs module, that is not supported in browsers. Hence, dree is not supported in browsers.

Here you can find useful pieces of information about the modules with no browser-support used in vuejs, maybe you could use it at build-time and not run-time.

[Unable to require 'fs' with Vue CLI 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420663/unable-to-require-fs-with-vue-cli-3/53502487)