# Check if folder exists in renderer process using Electron, React

Tags: reactjs, electron

I cannot seem to require it properly from the renderer process.

this is not working:

`const fs = window.require('fs').remote`

this is not working

`const fs = remote.require('fs')`

the function that uses it is like (using TypeScript):

```
private checkFolder = () => {
  fs.stat(this.state.targetLocationPath!, (err: any, stats: fs.Stats) => {
   console.log('stats', stats)
   this.setState({ isCreateButtonDisabled: !stats.isDirectory })
  })
}
```

Comment: I just use this: const fs = require('fs'); in the renderer process.

Comment: This answer looks like it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021584/5199262

Comment: It did actually, thank you!. What I had missing was the requiring of `remote`, it was actually undefined!. For some reason I thought `remote` would be intrinsically defined in an Electron app.