# importing fs in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, javascript-import

**hello everyone!**

I'm trying to import fs module in nodejs

first I was using require to import it like this

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

It was working fine for a while but suddenly stopped working and I'm getting this Error now

Error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

so I tried using Import to import it like this

```
import fs from 'node:fs'
```

and I tried many other ways for importing it using import and I'm getting this two Errors

Error1: **GET node:fs net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME**

Error2: **Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**

Is there any other ways for importing module in Nodejs? or the problem is my code? I've had many problems with fs module in nodejs, I've tried googling and I couldn't find any solution for this one, I appreciate you guys helping me.

*I'm using it to load a local file in Electronjs*

Thanks.

Comment: try this: `import * as fs from 'fs';`

Comment: declare ```"type" : "commonjs"``` in ```package.json```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use FS module inside Electron.Atom\WebPack application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994441/how-to-use-fs-module-inside-electron-atom-webpack-application)

Comment: Google CommonJs(using the require  syntax) and ES6 modules(newer with import) . They are different types of way of importing and have different extension as well as changes that could should be made in package.json

Comment: I tried that already but it's not working thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import fs from 'fs'
```

If you want the readfileSync directly, try:

```
import {readfileSync} from 'fs'
```

Also ensure that you add this to your package.json:

```
"type": "module"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure that you add this to your package.json:

```
"type": "module"
```